# Can we do getElementByID in AutoHotKey?

Tags: dom, vbscript, autohotkey, porting

I have this VBS code it works like a charm, but since Chrome doesn't support VB Scripts.

I need to find alternative which is autohotkey.

Can someone help me transform this code into AutoHotKey if not just section of it.

`Here is part of code` I need to do in AutoHotKey

```
  With IE.Document
    .getElementByID("login_username").value = "myuser"
    .getElementByID("login_password").value = "mypass"
    .getElementByID("frmLogin").submit
  End With
```

**Here is Full code**

```
WScript.Quit Main

Function Main
  Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
  IE.Visible = True
  IE.Navigate "http://desistream.tv/en/index.shtml"
  Wait IE
  With IE.Document
    .getElementByID("login_username").value = "myuser"
    .getElementByID("login_password").value = "mypass"
    .getElementByID("frmLogin").submit
  End With
End Function

Sub Wait(IE)
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy 
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy 
End Sub

Sub IE_OnQuit
  On Error Resume Next
  WScript.StdErr.WriteLine "IE closed before script finished."
  WScript.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#SingleInstance, force
#NoEnv
OnExit, ExitSub

IE := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible := true
IE.Navigate("http://desistream.tv/en/index.shtml")

Wait(IE)

pDoc := IE.document

pDoc.getElementByID("username").value := "myuser"
pDoc.getElementByID("pass").value := "mypass"
pDoc.all.frmLogin.submit()

return


+Esc::  ;shift + esc
ExitSub:
try
        IE.Quit
        IE := ""
Exitapp

Wait(IE) {
while IE.readyState!=4 || IE.document.readyState != "complete" || IE.busy
 sleep 10
}
```

Thats about it i think

hope it helps

Comment: Can you tell me is your totally based on AHK or some other?, I want to learn more.